# Click on particular instance for a button using CSS selector

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, css-selectors

I have a webpage which has multiple submit buttons. I want to loop through them and click on each of them one by one.

I know I can do it via xpath like this `(//button[@class='submit'])[i]` (where i = loop number).

But I wanted to know if it's possible to do via CSS selector?

I've tried `button.submit` but it will always click on the first button and I want to be able to loop through. I've also tried `button.submit:first-child` but it seems to do the same thing.

The following is similar to what the HTML is like.

```
<div>
    <button class="submit" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="submit" type="button"></button>
</div>
<div>
    <button class="submit" type="button"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try to `loop()` to _be able to loop_?

Comment: The loop isnt the issue. I need the css selector for my element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this such way:

If you are using Java version less than 8 do this way:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button.submit"));

WebElement confirm = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector_for_confirm"));

for(WebElement element: elements){
     element.click();
     confirm.click();
}
```

If you are using Java 8 or above, you can try this way:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("button.submit"));

WebElement confirm = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector_for_confirm"));

  elements.forEach(e->{
        e.click();
        confirm.click();
    });
```

Comment: If I understand correctly this will click on each element one after the other. But what if after clicking each button there is a confirmation modal where you have to click confirm?

For example you first click Submit, then you click confirm for each one.